# How To Eliminate Redundant Code In These Functions?

Tags: c#, dry

I've written some timing code for instructional purposes.  One set of code uses a bubble sort (demonstrates O(n^2) complexity) and the other uses quick sort (O(n log n)).  The function signatures differ; my bubble sort takes an int array and returns an int array while the quicksort takes an int array and modifies it in place--void return.  So this is the code I've gotten to time the operation:

```
    private delegate int[] ArrayFunc(int[] arr);
    private delegate void AlternateArrayFunc(int[] arr, int lbound, int ubound);

    private static long TimeOperation(ArrayFunc functionToTest,int[] arrayToSort, int[] correctResult) 
    {
        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        int[] resultArray = functionToTest.Invoke(arrayToSort);
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Debug.Assert(resultArray.SequenceEqual(correctResult), "Arrays do not match");
        return stopwatch.ElapsedTicks;
    }

    private static long TimeOperation(AlternateArrayFunc functionToTest, int[] arrayToSort, int[] correctResult)
    {
        var stopwatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        functionToTest.Invoke(arrayToSort, 0, arrayToSort.Length - 1);
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Debug.Assert(arrayToSort.SequenceEqual(correctResult), "Arrays do not match");
        return stopwatch.ElapsedTicks;
    }
```

I want just one TimeOperation function but I can't quite figure out how to deal with the two different delegates. I tried making the first argument a generic but I can't do that with a delegate--or at least I can't figure out how to do that anyway. If I make it a generic then it balks at the `.invoke` I really hate to keep the code this way since the only part that's different is the actual function I'm timing.

Any suggestions of how I might follow the DRY principle in this case?

Comment: try asking on [codereview.se]

Comment: Create an additional "entry point" method for your quick sort that just takes the array as a parameter. That entry point method could then call your recursive method that takes `lbound` and `ubound` parameters using `0` and `arr.Length - 1` for values.

Comment: Yeah I wasn't sure if this belonged on Code Review or here @DanielA.White.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an additional method for your quick sort that has the same signature as your bubble sort method:

```
public int[] QuickSortEntry(int[] arr)
{
    QuickSort(arr, 0, arr.Length - 1);
    return arr;
}
```

Or you could even just do this:

```
ArrayFunc qSort = arr => { QuickSort(arr, 0, arr.Length - 1); return arr; };
```

...and pass that into your timer method.